# How to fetch subcollections using streambuilder in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have subcollections in firestore database  and I want to fetch data from subcollections using streambuilder also use Listview.builder to show.

I have database like this

```
- Collection ->doc1->collection->doc->data
             ->doc2->collection->doc->data
             ->doc3->collection->doc->data
             ->doc4->collection->doc->data
             ->doc5->collection->doc->data
             ->doc6->collection->doc->data
```

Please write a query to fetch the data from database like this

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0):

For Future call:
you could use something like, if you don't know the next value for the document.
[image: Encapsulated collections and docs]

For streambuilder:
Would be to much heavy for encapsulated querys to make it.

1. One way to get values from a "col>doc>col>doc>data" is to get it directly like:

   Stream<UserData?>? get data {
   if(uid != null)
   return collectionsT.doc(uid).collection("col1").doc("doc2").snapshots().map(_dataFromSnapShot);
   return null;
   }
2. Replicating that data in a diferent shorter path collection.
3. Or saving the path in some kind of a "static" path Table> staticPath="doc/col/doc/col"

Normally "doc>col" structures are created in a way to have all the information that will be used in that screen that is designed to show, even if the information is replicated.
A trick is to calculate if the reads that will be done to that document with replicated information is lower than the updates. If that is the case, is needed a way to sync that information on the specific document. That is the information that google gives, by the video tutorials.